# Can't inject JavaScript into new tab from popup.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'M creating an extension that autofill's  forms on different websites. There is a portion of the script that records the actions of the user with event listeners. After the recording is done the user click the test button that will launch a new tab and autofill's the form. I know launching a new tab for testing is not necessary but this function will be used later for another feature.

This is what I got so far. I had started over several times. I tried sending a message to content script. The chrome.windows,create function only launched from the popup script. I started chrome development a week ago. I'm totally confused.

Popup.js

```
`(async () =\> { const tab = await chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://www.listyourself.net/ListYourself/listing.jsp'}); 
     const tabId = tab.id; if (!tab.url) 
      await onTabUrlUpdated(tabId); 
      await chrome.scripting.executeScript({ 
            target: {tabId}, 
            files: \['test.js'\],
        });`

  })();`
```

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions and host_permissions in manifest.json? Did you reload the extension after editing it? If so, debug the popup: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu, then go to Sources and set breakpoints in your code. If the code runs on the start of the popup you can press Ctrl-R inside the devtools window to restart the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I think your extension has two problems.

1. onTabUrlUpdated is not defined.
2. Execution of chrome.tabs.create causes the popup to lose focus, so the JavaScript is also terminated.

Here is a sample that fixes it.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "hoge"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  main();
});

const test = () => {
  console.log("test");
}

const main = async () => {
  const tab = await chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://nory-soft.web.app/" });
  const tabId = tab.id;
  if (!tab.url) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((updateTabId, changeInfo) => {
      if ((updateTabId == tabId) && (changeInfo.status == "complete")) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId },
          func: test
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a question. Could this only work from the background script? I have a popup ui that has a input box for the user to enter in a url and click the record button. After the record button is pressed inside the extension I want it to open the url in a different window and inject a script to record the users actions.